# Change CSS dropdown megamenu to Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, mouseleave

I have created a CSS dropdown menu, but the problem is on tablets, because it goes on hover, i have to change it on click to show and on click and mouseleave to hide. I have full working example in css.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="large-display sub-menus">
                <a class="arrow" href="#">SHOW</a>

                <div class="mega-menu full-width">
                    MENU
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/featzvzo/4/

Comment: For me, nothing happens when I hover it, so converting it to JS would be easy, it wouldn't really require anything ?

Comment: Just make it smaller, resize the results

Comment: Oh, okay, then it works!

Comment: The closest you get without using Javascript or jQuery is to use `:active`. But this effect is temporary when the mouse button is down. You will have to add some javascript to achieve what you want.

Comment: I need to change this to Jquery and add event click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/featzvzo/7/

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="large-display sub-menus"> 
        <a class="arrow" href="#">SHOW</a>
        <div class="mega-menu full-width">MENU</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.mega-menu {
    display:none;
}

.show {
    display:block;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.arrow').click(function () {
    $(this).next().addClass('show');
    $(this).next().on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is ok, but i need that on mouse leave to hide

Comment: @play2web: edited the code to work with mouseleave. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. whatever css properties you have applied on hover, make these all for a new class also such as active

So all hover properties will be now for active class properties too. Than on click on anchor tag will open submenu for that

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.menu li').on('click', function(){
     $(this).find('.mega-menu').css('visibility', 'visible');
     $(this).find('.mega-menu').css('opacity', '1');
    });
   })
```

Like this you can add jQuery to your menu. however you may need some more code to apply this jQuery menu such as for closing the menu again. but first tell me is it helpful. if it is I can help you further too

Comment: No i dont need class active only chnage behavior instead of hover in css just click

Comment: i edited the answer, please check it now.  no need to add any extra class and i think it might work for you now

Comment: Here is the perfect code for you question as i have check on your fiddle too.

Answer (score 0):

U cant use clickable element only using CSS. You need JS.

Working example:
[http://jsfiddle.net/a5Lh6tuc/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Lh6tuc/)

JS:

```
$('.arrow').click(function() {
    var $window = $(window);

    if($window.width() < 866)
    {
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
    }
})

$('body').click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;

    if (!$(target).is('.arrow')) {
        $('.arrow').closest('li').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

CSS modification:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 867px) {


.menu li:hover > ul,
.menu li:hover > .mega-menu,
.menu li:hover > .mega-menu ol li {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

    .menu li:hover > .mega-menu ol li {
        height: auto;
    }
        .menu ul ul li:hover > ul {
            position: relative;
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 866px) {


.menu li.active > ul,
.menu li.active > .mega-menu,
.menu li.active > .mega-menu ol li {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

    .menu li.active > .mega-menu ol li {
        height: auto;
    }
        .menu ul ul li.active > ul {
            position: relative;
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
}
```

1. U need define 2 resolution masks (width higher then 866px, and smaller)
2. Set-up them (hover effect or .active class)
3. Use JS
4. IF change resolution to higher then 866px, is active hover effect

Comment: Still when i leave mega-menu i want to be hidden

Comment: I edited example with hiding li - if is clicked somewhere else http://jsfiddle.net/a5Lh6tuc/2/